# Idiomatic way to call an async Rust function that takes a reference, when I'd want to pass ownership to the function

Tags: rust

There's a pattern I'm frequently encountering when writing async Rust code. Let's say I have a `Foo` struct (in real code, this could be something like a network client) and an async function that takes a reference to an instance of this struct:

```rust
struct Foo {
    i: i32
}

async fn use_foo(foo: &Foo) -> () {
    // do something with foo
}
```

Then, I want to run several `use_foo` concurrently, each with its own reference to a different `Foo`. A natural (but incorrect) way to do this would be:

```rust
use futures::stream::FuturesUnordered;

async fn foo_in_a_loop() {
    let futures = FuturesUnordered::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let foo = Foo { i };
        // does not compile: `foo` is dropped before the future is dropped
        futures.push(use_foo(&foo));
    }
}
```

which doesn't compile:

```
error[E0597]: `foo` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:53:30
   |
53 |         futures.push(use_foo(&foo));
   |                              ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
54 |     }
   |     - `foo` dropped here while still borrowed
55 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `futures` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `FuturesUnordered`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0597`
```

My question boils down to: **what's the most idiomatic way to fix this error?** I'd like to "force" `use_foo` to take ownership of the `Foo` instance.

Right now, I'm using a helper function that takes ownership of `foo`:

```
async fn use_foo_owned(foo: Foo) -> () {
    use_foo(&foo).await
}

async fn foo_in_a_loop_owned() {
    let futures = FuturesUnordered::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        let foo = Foo { i };
        futures.push(use_foo_owned(foo));
    }
}
```

which does compile, but introducing an extra function just to please the borrow checker is clunky.

Note that sometimes `use_foo` may come from another crate and I may not be able to change its signature, but if there's an elegant solution that involves modifying `use_foo`, I'm interested too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an `async move {}` block to create a future that takes ownership of `foo` and calls `use_foo`:

```
futures.push(async move { use_foo(&foo).await });
```